# Constructing Hasse diagram from a relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Is there a mathematical way to construct a Hasse / POSET diagram?

For instance, the transitive closure of $R$ will be a set of all the binary relations including those that are transitive.  It's my understanding if there are transitive relations or reflexive relations they should be removed for the Hasse diagram.  Unsure if there is some mathematical language to describe this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of a set $X$ with a relation $R$ as a directed graph (with vertex set $X$ and edge set $R$), then this is called a [transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) of the graph, or a *minimum equivalent digraph*. According to Wikipedia, these differ in that transitive reductions are allowed to introduce new edges (which don't change reachability), whereas minimum equivalent digraphs are always subgraphs of the original. Other sources don't necessarily make this distinction. For a finite acyclic graph, the transitive reduction is unique and is always a subgraph.

If the relation is a partial order, the reduced relation is called the [covering relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation).

Comment: This is helpful.  For the transitive reduction, would one construct the transitive closure first then reduce it using the covering relation? The covering relation being for set $X$, a relation $R \subset X \times X$. $R_{trc} = \{(x,z) | (x,z) \in R^{+} \land \lnot \exists y \in X ((x,y) \in R \land (y,z) \in R)  \}$

Comment: I created $X = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ and $R=\{(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(0,3)\}$.  I looked at the *cover* and in this case $(0,3)$, $3$ would be a cover of $0$, which it should not be.  So my assumption is that the transitive closure must be computed first.  Is this correct?

Comment: The transitive reduction of the transitive closure would be the same as the transitive reduction, so there isn't a need to do the closure first. In your example, $R$ is not a partial order, so the definition of covering relation doesn't directly apply; if you look at the implied partial order, 3 is not covering 0. But the transitive reduction is still defined, and would remove the edge (0,3).

Comment: @Nick The covering relation for a poset could also be described as the transitive reflexive reduction, i.e. removing the reflexive property of the poset; a drawing of this would be the Hasse diagram. If we just take the transitive reduction of a poset, technically, we are left with loops at each "vertex" as well.

Comment: @Christopher.L thanks.  The covering relation is the solution to creating the Hasse diagram.